# Microsoft Word: Can I turn endnotes into a bibliography?

Tags: software-rec, microsoft-word, bibliography

I'm using Chicago Manual of Style.

If not, is there a software that does it? (preferably free)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with any software that might be able to do that, but there is a free webapp that will format a Bibliography for you, in any style you need...

> Bibme.org - http://www.bibme.org/